# eclipseとoracleを接続する際のデータ定義と接続情報について

Tags: database

[TERASOLUNAのチュートリアル](http://terasoluna.osdn.jp/tutorial/server-web/Document/WebTutorial_3.1.html)

でデータベースをOracle DBに切り替える作業を行っているのですが、

「データベースへの接続に失敗しました。
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor」

というエラーが出てしまいます。

接続情報は
データベース定義名：TERASOLUNA
JDBCドライバー: odbc6jar

JDBC Driver：oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
JDBC タイプ：Type4
接続文字列：jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.11.89:1521:ORCL（ipはコマンドのipconfigで調べました）
接続ユーザ：taro（SQLコマンドでUSERを作成）
接続パスワード：パスワード（SQLコマンドで作成）

以上の設定で接続を試してみましたが、うまくいきません。

TERASOLUNAのチュートリアルと自分のPC環境設定と照らし合わせて、接続情報の引き出し方はこれであっているか。
確認しておくべき点をご教授願いたいのですが、お願いします。

Comment: 自己解決できました。ありがとうこざいました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の記事に確認すべき事項と、対処方法が説明されていますから参考になるのではないでしょうか。
[ORA-12505: TNS: リスナーは接続記述子で指定されたSIDを現在認識していません](http://www.noguopin.com/oracle/index.php?ORA-12505)